# CakePHP how send email notification

Tags: email, cron, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to send email notification to some users via cron job in my app.

After a few hours of reading, I've understood that the best way to do that is using Shell.

Please can someone help me to understand how to do that, how can I use one myShell class's different actions to send different notifications? I mean that how can cron access to myShell different actions.

for example.

```
<?php
  class MyShell extends Shell { 

    function send_task_notifications(){
      .... //this must send email every day at 00:00 am
    }

    function send_new_post_notifications() {
      .... //this must send email every week//
    }

  }
?>
```

Both of this actions are in MyShell class.

So how can I call one of them via Cron and is this MyShell class accessible by the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Your shell need to change in the following way, you need to pass a parameters based on that parameters it will execute email notification/push notification. Move your functions to a component it will work

```
<?php
  class MyShell extends Shell { 

    function main()
    {
        $option = !empty($this->args[0]) ? $this->args[0] : ”;
        echo ‘Cron started without any issue.’;

        App::import(‘Component’, 'MyOwnComponent');
        $this->MyOwnComponent = &new MyOwnComponent();
        switch ($option)
        {
            case 'task_notifications':
                    $this->MyOwnComponent->send_task_notifications();
                break;
           case 'post_notifications':
                    $this->MyOwnComponent->send_new_post_notifications();
                break;
            default:
            echo 'No Parameters passed .';
        }

    }
  }
?>
```

Your Component file as follows

```
<?php
class MyOwnComponent extends Object
{
 function send_task_notifications(){
      .... //this must send email every day at 00:00 am
    }

 function send_new_post_notifications() {
      .... //this must send email every week//
    }
}

?>
```

For more details refer the link http://cakephpsaint.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/6-steps-to-create-cron-jobs-in-cakephp/